Java Sql Query display on jsp
I am creating the front end with jsp and I have an input. This input allows user to type in a sql query. (there is no validation at this point of time).
Let's say on submit, it goes to a controller call queryResult.
I am able to execute the query. But how can I use the result and display them as a table?
I took the text input. Used that in createNativeQuery.

You can display the table data using JSP scripting. I suggest you do a quick search using this string "How to display values in table in jsp?". There are many examples online.
